# How do I divide 2 int arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, division

Suppose you are in base 10.

You want to divide int[] a = new int[] {9, 9};

by int[] b = new int[] {1, 0, 1};

Every element in both arrays contain a single digit.

On paper it would look like 99/101, which would give you a repeating decimal.

How do I do this without converting/combining either array into an int?

Comment: You could use `Strings` and `parseDouble()`...

Comment: And you would pretty much need to put it into a numerical value in order to do the calculation with a method.

Comment: Why can't you combine the arrays into an int? Is this a homework dump?

Comment: You'll pretty much need to implement long division exactly the way you learned it, which will be a huge pain.

Comment: I'll try to write an algorithm for it

Comment: It's impossible with your phrasing 'converting/combining either array into an int`, any division requires an integer combination, is that how the question is worded?

Answer (score 1):

If the array is long, you can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

First of all, convert the array into a string and construct the `BigInteger` using the string. 
Then, do arithmetic using two `BigInteger`.

Here is the code to convert the array into a `BigInteger`.

```
public BigInteger convert2BigInteger(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int v : arr) {
        sb.append(v);
    }
    return new BigInteger(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public double divideArrayContent(int[] a, int[] b) {
       int aT = 0;
       int bT = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           aT += a[a.length - (i + 1)] * 10 ^ i;
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
           bT += b[b.length - (i + 1)] * 10 ^ i;
       }
       return aT / bT;
   }
```

This should work, but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int []a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int c = 1;
int result = 0;
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(i == a.length-1){
        result += a[i]; 
    }else{
        c = c * 10;
        result += a[i] * c;
    }
}
```